# PostgreSql Dynamic JSON Indexing

Tags: postgresql, indexing

I am new to PostgreSql world. We chose this DB so that we could query our JSON results for filter queries like contains, less than , greater than, etc. JSON results are dynamic and we cannot know in advance what keys will be generated as the output.    Table (result_id (int64),jsondata(jsonb)) data looks like this

```
id1,{k1:vab,k2:abc,k3:def}
id1,{k1:abv,k2:v7,k3:ghu}
id1,{k1:v5,k2:vdd,k3:vew}
id1,{k1:v6,k2:v9s,k3:ved}
id2,{k4:vw,k5:vds,k6:vdss}
id2,{k4:v1,k5:fgg,k6:dd}
id2,{k4:qw,k5:gfd,k6:ess}
id2,{k4:er,k5:dfs,k6:fss}
```

My queries would be something like

```
Select * from table where result_id = 'id1' and jsondata->'k1' contains 'ab'
```

My script outputs a json content that I store in this table.
Each json key is represented in a Grid column and json key's values are column data.Grid offers filtering capabilities, which means filtering on JSON data.
My problem is that the filtering can happen on any JSON key, but key names are not static. Keys (json output) might change when the script content is changed So previously indexed keys would become irrelevant.  But if the script is not changed the keys remain constant.

How do I apply indexing so that my JSON filter operations become faster? The same table contains many keys within the same JSON row and across rows. Wouldn't it be inefficient to index all keys so that filtering can be made efficient?

Comment: From [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-json.html), it looks like a GIN index would benefit you

Comment: Thanks. I was leaning towards GIN indexes already. You confirmed the approach.